# How to test that a custom event from was fired from child component

Tags: testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I've a `Vue` component with the following structure

```
// parent-component.vue
<main>
  <component :is="my.component" @custom-event="callback"/>
</main>
```

The child component has always have the following `mixin`

```
// child-shared-mixin.js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('custom-event')
  },
}
```

Here is the example of the child component

```
// child-component.vue
<script>
  import { ChildSharedMixin } from 'mixins'

  export default {
    mixins: [
      ChildSharedMixin
    ],
  }
</script>
```

So, whenever the `child` is mounted I trigger a event to the parent and then execute a callback.

With `Jest` and `Vue Test Utils` how can I test that `mixin` has fired the `custom-event`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> emitted() Return an object containing custom events emitted by the
>   Wrapper vm.

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#emitted

so to test the child component, you can do:

```
describe('myComponent',()={
    it('should trigger custom-event on mounted hook',()=>{
        let target=mount(myComponent);
        expect(target.emitted()['custom-event']).toBeTruthy();
    })
})
```

and to test the parent component, you go the other way around- by mocking the event and expecting the callback to get invoked. take a look at:

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/trigger.html

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I was not testing the child component.

Comment: since this specific event happens on mounted hook, you dont have to mock it. just make sure it really happened, by overriding the callback with your own stub and check if it got called: `describe('parent',()={
    it('should trigger custom-event on mounted hook',()=>{
        lat callback=sinon.stub();
        let options={
            methods:{
                callback,
            }
        }
        let target=mount(parent,options);
       expect(callback.called).toBe(true);
    })
})`